# Escape Characters in JSON Data

Tags: json, r, twitter, unicode-escapes

I start with

```
   mentions = GET(final_url, sig)
   json = content(mentions)
```

My code crashes at the next line which is

```
   json2 = jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON(json))
```

Giving error...

```
    Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
      Foundation and 42nd President of the United States. Follow 
                 (right here) ------^
```

I'm dealing with some JSON data. 
One small piece of it looks like this.  That is, this is the output from my variable "json".

```
    Lots of JSON before this....

    $statuses[[99]]$retweeted_status$user$location
    [1] "New York, NY"

    $statuses[[99]]$retweeted_status$user$description
    [1] "Founder, Clinton Foundation and 42nd President \003of the United                States. Follow @clintonfdn for \003more on my work around the world."

    $statuses[[99]]$retweeted_status$user$url
    [1] "http://t.co/gI8TIlAJHk"
```

As you can see, there is escape character \003 embedded in one of the pieces of JSON data.

I'm dealing with hundreds of pieces of good information in the same file, but this could happen anywhere thinking of it now.  Sure this time it happened in "description" but it could happen in a tweet, in a location, in a description, etc.

Is there a way to "clean" escape characters from JSON before trying to do jsonlite::fromJSON(toJSON()) to avoid my code crashing here?

Comment: One of my text editors (on a Mac) has a "remove NonASCII characters" facility. You might try passing your JSON file through such an editing step.

Answer (score 2):

You could try somthing like this:

```
 json2 <- gsub("[\001-\026]*", "", json)
```

Here's a simple "test of strategy"

```
> gsub("[\003-\005]*", '', "\003\004\005\027abc")
[1] "\027abc"
```

If you need a better test, you should post output of `dput(head(json))`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

I tried converting my original before the json conversion.

That is, I did: json = gsub("[\001-\026]*", "", json )  so that I overwrote my json variable before I did json2 = jsonlite::blahblahblah.    Doing your idea gives me "Error in toJSON(json) : Unable to escape string.  String is not utf8"

Comment: To add, I tried to do dput(head(json)) as requested.  The R environment bugs out, and only partially displays it.  I'm still pretty unfamiliar with that, so I can't really provide it.  I think you're method is onto something though.  Will investigate converting it to UTF8.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. It was strange behavior that the utf-8 error in my R Script ran just fine on my local workstation but not anymore when I deployed it on servers.